# How to change button content when clicked in Xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have buttoncontent named Hold button. Once when I clicked button the button content should change to Resume, again if pressed resume button means Hold should be visible.

XAML code:

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource CommonButtonStyle}" Template="{DynamicResource GlassButton}" ToolTip="F9" Click="Hold_Click" PreviewKeyDown="Hold_PreviewKeyDown" Name="OK" Margin="1,49,25,0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="13" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ButtonStackPanel}">
            <Image Style="{StaticResource CancelImages}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Loc lblHold}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonTextBlock}" />
        </StackPanel>
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try something like this in the button's `Click` event:

```
private void holdResumeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        if ((string)holdResumeButton.Content == "Hold")
            holdResumeButton.Content = "Resume";

        else
            holdResumeButton.Content = "Hold";

}
```

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="holdResumeButton" 
        Content="Hold"
        Click="holdResumeButton_Click"/>
```

Comment: Using Code behind when XAML lets you do it is not a good solution. See @Dennis solution.

Answer (score 7):

Use `ToggleButton`:

```
        <Style x:Key="HoldOrResumeButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock Text="Hold"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TextBlock Text="Resume"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `ToggleButton` instead of `Button` so you can bind to `IsChecked` property.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx

For example:

```
    <ToggleButton x:Name="TB">
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ToggleButton.Content" Value="Resume"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
```