# Change Label Text to ListBox Selected Item's Text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

## The Problem

I'm trying to change the Text of a Label on another window to the value of a selected item within a listbox on the first window.

I've tried using:

```
Window1.FoodLabel.Text= this.ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

But the button will say *"Windows.System..."*

The ListBox's Template is edited if that has anything to do with it. I can't figure anything out to such simple problem.

## XAML for the ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Margin="0,23,0,43" Background="#FF313131" Style="{DynamicResource Seeds}" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" SelectionChanged="ListBox1_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBoxItem x:Name="Barley" Content="Barley" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource SeedItem}" Selected="Barley_Selected"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Bean" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle1}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="BlueBerry" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle2}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Chili" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle3}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Corn" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle4}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Cucumber" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle5}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Garlic" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle6}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Millet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle7}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Oat" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle8}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Onion" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle9}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Peanut" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle10}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Potato" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle11}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Pumpkin" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle12}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Quinoa" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle13}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Rice" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle14}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Rye" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource SeedItem}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Strawberry" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle15}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Tomato" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle16}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Wheat" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle17}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Yam" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle18}"/>
</ListBox>
```

I've tried this as well, which seemed like it would work:

```
 Window1 window1 = new Window1();
     window1.FoodLabel.Content = (ListBoxItem)this.ListBox1.SelectedValue.Content.ToString();
     window1.Show();
```

But Visual Studio gives me this error:

[image]

Comment: is this windows or wpf app...?

Comment: It's WPF, tagged it @MethodMan

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting value of selected item in list box as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003095/getting-value-of-selected-item-in-list-box-as-string)

Comment: @RufusL I've tried that solution, it didn't work for me.

Comment: can you show more code ..? especially the xaml you are using this may help but can't tell with what little code you have provided http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540343/how-to-change-button-content-when-clicked-in-xaml

Comment: Shouldn't this `this.ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` not be `this.ListBox1.SelectedItem.Content`?

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding the question correctly -- you just want to be able to get the text for the selected ListBoxItem?

I would think

```
Window1.FoodLabel.Text= (string) this.ListBox1.SelectedItem.Content;
```

would do it.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Window1.FoodLabel.Text = (ListBoxItem)this.ListBox1.SelectedValue).Content.ToString();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind it :

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=ListBox1, Path=SelectedItem.Content}"
```

Or you can set Text on SelectionChanged event:

```
TbTimeDispPopup.Text = (string)((ListBoxItem)ListBox1.SelectedItem).Content;
```

Hope this helps!